# Getting "Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID" after installing xcode on an external drive

Tags: xcode

After struggling with space issues I finally bought an external drive for my Mac. I deleted my existing copy of XCode that was installed on the internal drive, downloaded the latest version from the apple developer site, and installed that to the external drive. I can open & build my project just fine, but when it comes to running it in the simulator, I get the following error:

"Failed to create IXPlaceholder for app bundle ID"

I did search on that, and found some answers that boiled down to "run xcode-setup --install", which I did, but it did not fix the issue.

The simulator does come up & run, it just doesn't load my project.

I'm pretty new to Mac/Xcode development, so hoping this is something basic I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your derived data first if not work try;

Go to your project and once you are on the `build phases` tab you should see a section that says `Embed App Extensions`, click on to extend.

Now that you will see a opened `Embed App Extension`s you should see a checkbox that says **Copy only when installing.** You need to check that checkbox.

Comment: Tried both those - no luck, get the same error.

Comment: pls check this thread same error with yours: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/91090